# Como popular um select ou checkbox dinamicamente usando annotations no Zend Form do ZF 2?

Tags: zend, html-select, zend-framework-2, annotation

Eu aprendi a fazer isso com valores fixos, exemplo:

```
@Annotation\Type("Zend\Form\Element\Select")
@Annotation\Options({"label":"Cidade"})
@Annotation\Attributes({"options":{"1":"São Paulo","2":"Rio de Janeiro"}})
```

Porém, como eu coloco esse options para exibir dados de uma tabela do banco de dados, como por exemplo tabela cidades?

E no caso de um checkbox, seria a mesma coisa?

Answer (score 0):

RESOLVIDO:

```
@Form\Type("DoctrineModule\Form\Element\ObjectSelect")
@Form\Options({"label":"Pessoa", "target_class":"Pessoa\Entity\Pessoa","find_method":{"name":"findBy","params":{"criteria":{}, "orderBy":{"nome":"ASC"}}},"display_empty_item":true,"empty_item_label":"---"}))
```

Resolveu meu problema.

Comment: sabe quando o zend vai virar laminas?